# Scanner.next returning path of file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner:

```
m = new Scanner(Values.mazegen.replace("\\","//") + "//maze.txt");
```

(Values.mazegen.replace("\","//") + "//maze.txt" prints as C://users//myusername//Desktop)
and when I use `m.next()`
it returns `C://users//myusername//Desktop//maze.txt`. I have no idea why...?
Full code:

```
public void openFile(){
        try {
            if(Values.custom == true && Values.customSolved == false){
            m = new Scanner(new File(Values.MazeFile));
            }else if(Values.customSolved == true || Values.custom == false){
            m = new Scanner(Values.mazegen.replace("\\","//") + "//Maze.txt");
            }else{
                m = new Scanner(Values.mazegen.replace("\\","//") + "//Maze.txt");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
        if(Values.custom == true && Values.customSolved == false){
            m.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        System.out.println("Got this far...");
        while(m.hasNext()){
            for(int i = 0; i < Values.x; i++){
                Maze[i] = m.next();
                System.out.println(Maze[i]);
            }
            m.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        m.close();
    }
```

(OpenFile, readFile, and closeFile are executed in order)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) scans the string literal you pass it, not a file. to scan a file use `new Scanner(new File("path to file"))`

Also you shouldn't be using double forward slashes.

Comment: @user3042719 you're not the first.  This question has been asked here many times.